# How to execute "execCommand" in an iFrame with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, execcommand

for example:

i click a button. And a div is changeing someting

```
$('#change').click(function(){ //the button
  $('#myframe').contents().find('#makeit').css("do Someting") //the div in a frame
});
```

So far i've understand.

I need to know, how can i execute an execCommand (maybe like 'bold') instead of a .css() methode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365851/execcommand-for-iframe-dont-work/).

In my case (jQuery). It looks like

```
$('#change').click(function(){
   document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to target execCommand() on an element with id "makeit"?

I'm afraid that's not possible, since it's `document.execCommand(String commandName, Bool showUI, Variant value)` which executes the command based on the selection / caret focus.

Read eg. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla for details.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention the div is contendeditable="true". i want to change the content in the div(id="makeit"). which is in a iframe